# What are best ways to improve thermal performance on Dell Latitude E5570 running Ubuntu?

Tags: dell, overheating

I am running Ubuntu on my Dell latitude E5570, but it heating up quickly after booting. On the other side, running Win 10 it was quite cool (CPU 40 C or below). The part of the cover below which is SSD is also quite hot with Ubuntu...

Comment: Do you have the processor microcode in use? Go to System Settings → Software & Updates → Additional Drivers. There is likely an "Unknown Device" with the options either not to use it or to use some Intel firmware/microcode stuff. Make sure that the latter is selected.

Comment: There is no "unknown device"

Comment: Are there any items in the list?

Comment: Nope. It's empty

Comment: For my Dell Inspiron 17R 7720 SE I had all kinds of problems until I found and installed `TLP`. Avoid `I8Kfan` like the plague as it causes machine to pause every 10 seconds. You should also have `Thermald` and `Powerclamp` installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The Good news and the Bad news about overheating

The good news is there are lots of answers in ***Ask Ubuntu*** dealing with overheating so you should be able to find a combination of solutions to deal with the issue.

The bad news is there are lots of answers in ***Ask Ubuntu*** dealing with overheating so there are lots of other users with overheating issues.

## Summary of experience with Dell Inspiron 17R 7720 SE

Each laptop model can require different "tweaking" for CPU frequency, Turbo Boost, Hyper-Threading, Fan Speed and battery life. The answers I've written are based on my Dell Laptop. Here are the answers I've written for others with overheating issues:

- [Bash script to sleep at given CPU temperature ~ update for 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206214/bash-script-to-sleep-at-given-cpu-temperature-update-for-16-04/876732#876732)
- [How to set "Performance" instead of "Powersave" as default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929884/how-to-set-performance-instead-of-powersave-as-default/936488#936488)
- [Stop cpu from overheating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/391474/stop-cpu-from-overheating/875872#875872)
- [Laptop running hot under ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852502/laptop-running-hot-under-ubuntu/852918#852918)
- [What causes my fan to run?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/853209/what-causes-my-fan-to-run/853314#853314)
- [No version of Ubuntu can be installed with any Skylake 6th generation Intel processor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/691216/no-version-of-ubuntu-can-be-installed-with-any-skylake-6th-generation-intel-proc/852910#852910)

## Which is the best link?

From the answers I've written I feel [Stop cpu from overheating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/391474/stop-cpu-from-overheating/875872#875872) is the best link for you. However I've included all the links because answers written by other users will probably be helpful and some might even be better for your laptop.